# Multiple video sources combined into one

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-processing, flash-video, processing-efficiency

I am looking for an efficient way to do the following:

Using several source videos (of approximately the same length), I need to generate an output video that is composed of all of the original sources each running in its own area (like a bunch of [PIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture-in-picture)s in several different sizes). So, the end result is that all the original are running side-by-side, each in its own area/box.

The source and output need to be `flv` and the platform I am using is Windows (dev on Windows 7 64bit, deployment to Windows server 2008).

I have looked at [avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) but unfortunately it can't handle `flv` and non of the plugins and flv splitters I have tried worked.

My current process uses [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) in the following manner:

1. Use ffmpeg to generate 25 png's per second per video, resizing the original as needed.
2. Use the `System.Drawing` namespace to combine each set of frames into a new image, starting with a static background, then loading each frame into an `Image` and drawing to the background `Graphics` object - this gives me the combined frames.
3. Use ffmpeg to combine the generated images to a video.

All this is very IO intensive (which is my processing bottleneck at the moment) and I feel there must be a more efficient way to reach my goal. I do not have much experience with video processing, and don't know what options are out there.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of processing these?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do everything inside ffmpeg. You can do a lot of things with [video filters](http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html). For example to join two videos side by side:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.avi -vf "movie=input1.avi [in1]; [in]pad=640*2:352[in0]; [in0][in1] overlay=640:0 [out]" out.avi
```

@Oded: That's basically what this command does. You can remove the `pad` filter and change the parameters of `overlay` filter to move the second video wherever you like.

```
ffmpeg -i big.avi -vf "movie=small.avi [small]; [in][small] overlay=10:10 [out]" out.avi
```

The link I provided describes the filter syntax. You can chain multiple filters together:

```
ffmpeg -i big.avi -vf "movie=small0.avi [small0]; [in][small0] overlay=10:10 [tmp];\
                       movie=small1.avi [small1]; [tmp][small1] overlay=30:10 [out]" out.avi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - do you have an example of a picture-in-picture command line?

Comment: Great second example - how would I specify more than 2 sources? Or would I need to call it multiple times with different overlays?

Comment: It looks like `overlay` does not resize the originals - I assume I will need to use `scale` for that?

Comment: @Oded: It looks that way. `overlay` takes only `x:y` arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Banthar for the solution. Got my stitching done with this, beautifully. :) Stitched video can be viewed here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX4aY8_jv9U

Comment: This is the command line I used to split the two videos down the middle: `ffmpeg -i in1.webm -vf "in2.webm [in1];[in1]crop=640:720:640:0[in3]; [in]pad=640*2:0[in0]; [in0][in3] overlay=640:0 [out]" -crf 5 -b:v 8M out.webm`

Comment: Would a vstack or a hstack be better than pad + overlay?