# How to merge four videos on one screen with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video test.mp4, and I need to make it appear four times at once on a screen.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581665/multiple-video-sources-combined-into-one) I found a command that makes two videos appear at a time

```
ffmpeg -i input0.avi -vf "movie=input1.avi [in1]; [in]pad=640*2:352[in0]; [in0][in1] overlay=640:0 [out]" out.avi
```

But it doesn't work with mp4 videos, and I need four videos at a time.